# Error during Insert entries from xml file to Oracle Database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

for a school project I've to add to my db some data found online. I've a huge xml file like this:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <row Id="-1007" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2021-09-30T18:39:12.143" DisplayName="EX1" LastAccessDate="2021-09-30T18:39:12.143" AboutMe="..." Views="0" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" />
  <row Id="-1006" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2021-09-27T19:40:44.437" DisplayName="EX2" LastAccessDate="2021-09-27T19:40:44.437" AboutMe="..." Views="0" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" />
  <row Id="-1005" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2021-07-29T14:07:57.580" DisplayName="EX3" LastAccessDate="2021-07-29T14:07:57.580" AboutMe="..." Views="0" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" />
</users>
```

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
 Id  NUMBER,
 Reputation  NUMBER,
 CreationDate    TIMESTAMP,
 DisplayName VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
 LastAccessDate  TIMESTAMP,
 AboutMe VARCHAR2(500),
 Views   INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 UpVotes INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
 DownVotes   INTEGER DEFAULT 0,   
 CONSTRAINT PK_USERS PRIMARY KEY(Id) 
);
```

So, I've tried to write an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO USERS (Id, Reputation, CreationDate, DisplayName,LastAccessDate,AboutMe,Views,UpVotes,DownVotes)
SELECT MY_XML.row.query('Id').value('.', 'NUMBER'),
       MY_XML.row.query('Reputation').value('.', 'NUMBER'),
       MY_XML.row.query('CreationDate').value('.', 'TIMESTAMP'),
       MY_XML.row.query('DisplayName').value('.', 'VARCHAR2(100)'),
       MY_XML.row.query('LastAccessDate').value('.', 'TIMESTAMP'),
       MY_XML.row.query('AboutMe').value('.', 'VARCHAR2(500)'),
       MY_XML.row.query('Views').value('.', 'INTEGER'),
       MY_XML.row.query('UpVotes').value('.', 'INTEGER'),
       MY_XML.row.query('DownVotes').value('.', 'INTEGER')
  FROM (
        SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
          FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
        ) AS T(MY_XML)
  CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('users/row') AS MY_XML (Customer);
```

But it gives me this error below

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

It's my first time with this kind of things. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you run just the select part ( remove the insert), what comes back?

Comment: Somehow your SQL statements resemble MS SQL Server T-SQL syntax. Though the error comes from Oracle.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky is right, it's invalid syntax for Oracle. `AS` keyword cannot be used for tables or aliases in Oracle's SQL. Moreover Oracle doesn't have `OPENROWSET` unlike to `MS SQL Server`.

Comment: How can I rewrite it in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use SQL Server syntax to parse an XML document in an Oracle database.  This won't work.  You will need to use Oracle syntax instead.

Also, Oracle can't read an arbitrary file off the filesystem just by passing the filename.  Instead, you will need to create a directory somewhere on your machine (or use an existing directory), and then create an Oracle directory object corresponding to this filesystem directory.  Oracle can only read files off the filesystem when given a directory object and a filename.

If your directory is `C:\example`, then you'll need to copy your `users.xml` file into `C:\example` and run something like:

```sql
CREATE DIRECTORY EXAMPLE_DIR AS 'C:\example`;
```

Once you've got this set up, something like the following should be able to read the data out of your XML file and into your table:

```sql
INSERT INTO USERS (Id, Reputation, CreationDate, DisplayName, LastAccessDate, AboutMe, Views, UpVotes, DownVotes)
SELECT Id, Reputation, TO_TIMESTAMP(CreationDateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), DisplayName, TO_TIMESTAMP(LastAccessDateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), AboutMe, Views, UpVotes, DownVotes
  FROM XMLTABLE(
        '/users/row'
        PASSING XMLTYPE(BFILENAME('EXAMPLE_DIR', 'users.xml'), NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8'))
        COLUMNS
            Id INTEGER PATH '@Id',
            Reputation INTEGER PATH '@Reputation',
            CreationDateStr VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) PATH '@CreationDate',
            DisplayName VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@DisplayName',
            LastAccessDateStr VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) PATH '@LastAccessDate',
            AboutMe VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@AboutMe',
            Views VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@Views',
            UpVotes VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@UpVotes',
            DownVotes VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) PATH '@DownVotes'
    );
```

The expression `'/users/row'` selects all the rows from the file after it gets parsed as XML.  Note we supply the name of the Oracle directory and the filename in the call to `BFILENAME`.  Then in the `COLUMNS` clause we pull out the data of interest for each `row` element.

I found it easier to pull the dates out of the `XMLTABLE` call as strings and parse them as timestamps afterwards.  There might be a way of parsing them to timestamps in XPath/XQuery, but the above appears to work.

Comment: You can just declare the column as `TIMESTAMP` - in this context it even allows the `T` ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bac2968a965bda243919743198ef18ac)).

Comment: @AlexPoole: thanks for that, indeed you can, which does simplify things: as well as removing the calls to `TO_TIMESTAMP` you can replace the entire list of `SELECT`ed columns with `*`. I guess this works because the format of the timestamp in the sample XML matches the format of date-time values that the XPath/XQuery engine expects.  It certainly doesn't match `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`, and I was keen to not have my answer dependent on NLS settings like that.

Comment: yes, the XML value has to be ISO-8601 (and requires, rather than allows, the `T`). It also supports time zone offsets (and `Z`) if you declare the column as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward It gives me error ORA-22288 even if it as all permission :(

Comment: @Loki00 The user account that the Oracle database is running as needs access to the filesystem directory created. Another thing to try is to create another directory somewhere else on the filesystem, e.g. one under `C:\Users\YourUsername\`. These are my best guesses as to what you've missed.  In your comment you wrote "all permission", and if all permissions on both the filesystem and within Oracle had been granted, then the code in my answer would work. Without any further information on exactly what you've tried, I can only guess at what you've missed.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I've send ```grant read, write on directory EXAMPLE_DIR to public;``` to console to grant access, but nothing worked :( I've tried also to change directory but the error shows up. I have used ```SYS``` account

Comment: @Loki00: you need to change the permissions on the filesystem directory, not the Oracle directory.  Use Windows File Explorer to change these permissions.